# Where is PATH defined in CentOS?

Tags: bash, centos, centos7

I started looking into files such as:

- /etc/profile
- ~/.bash_profile
- etc.

in order to locate where environment variables were defined. Unfortunately, I couldn't locate the $PATH variable. I am using Bash.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The initial `PATH` environment variable is inherited from ... whatever launched the shell.  For example commands like `sudo`, `sshd`, whatever creates your shall after a desktop login.

There also appears to be a `PATH` that is hardwired into the `bash` binary for cases where an initial `PATH` is not inherited.  (Look at the output from `strings /bin/bash`.)

Then various shell initialization scripts get a go at setting or updating `PATH`.  For example, on Ubuntu the `PATH` variable is updated by `/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh` ... which is run by `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score -1):

You should not worry (or even ask) where `PATH` is set, since you should not be trusting a random distro to put the right directories in the right sequence.

Instead, you set the `PATH` you need in your shell's profile. That's it.

As a starting point, POSIX mandates that `getconf PATH` returns the system's default `PATH`. If you have a `$HOME/bin` and there's a `/usr/local/bin`, then you add them.
Here's what this looks like on my machine:

```
PATH="$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)"
PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin"
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

With this setup, it's easy to adapt the sequence. Maybe you don't like the ancient vim in `/usr/bin/vi`? Compile it yourself and move `/usr/local/bin` to the front.